# Send mass email with Gmail API

Tags: email, gmail-api

I want to send mass email with GMail API. 
Currently I add all the addresses at the To section.
But every recipient should receive the mail and see only his address and not the other ones. Is there a method/API that I can use for this?

Comment: That's what BCC is for.

Comment: And that's not really a question about Gmail's API. That's just how email works.

Comment: I'm aware of that too, but I needed something like GMass. Each receiver should revecive an email and his address should be in the To section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Gmail was not created for sending bulk emails as it restricts the number of recipients and has tons of other limitations. You should try to use third-party service for this.

[Here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en) you can find Gmail API limitation. It says

> 100 Recipients per message sent via SMTP (by POP or IMAP users) or the Gmail API

Comment: Yes, Gmail has been known to close accounts for spamming.